# Laravel 5.* modify column with migration

Tags: laravel-5, migration

I have follow the laravel migration steps and its good. My problem is about on modifying the column. I already installed the doctrine\dbal in composer. But when i change the column `$table->string('name')->nullable()->change()` with change method, then run php artisan migrate. Is says nothing to migrate. Why? Do i need to use the doctrin\dbal like this `use Doctine\dbal` in the migration table class? Or what is the better way to implement for modifying the table column in migration and what artisan should i run? Any help please!

Comment: Have you created a new migration to change the field? If not, then you must create a new migration as the migration which you have changed is already registered as being complete so will not run again.

Comment: So meaning, the old migration has no effect even if i changed anything?

Comment: No, the old migration has already been run so will not run again. You need to create a new migration file to change an exisiting table, or, you can re-run all your migrations using the command `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBolton for your reply. It really helps. God bless you.

Comment: I have now posted the above as an answer, if you feel this is correct, please could you accept this answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenancy migrations will only run once, meaning once it has been run, it will not run again once the `php artisan migrate` has been run. You can see all migrations which have been run in your application by viewing the migrations table in your database.

If you edit a migration file and need to re-run all your migrations you can use the following command `php artisan migrate:refresh`. This will rollback all your migrations and re-run them and also increment the batch number on the migrations table.

If you need to edit one of your tables but don't need to re-run all your migrations, you should create a new migration and edit the table in question in that particular migration. Once the `migrate` command has been run again, only your new migration will be executed.

You can find more information on all of this in the following link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations